# Как запустить eel функцию после нажатия на кнопку с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, python, eel

Пишу веб-интерфейс с помощью eel, где не обойтись без javascript-а, и возникла проблема, я написал функцию Parce в gui.py, которая запускает парсер интернет-магазина(он работает отлично), и я хочу что бы при нажатии на кнопку он запускался, но как правильно отследить нажатие на кнопку с помощью js?

Вот сама страница
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержание gui.py:

```
import eel
import os
@eel.expose
def Parce():
    subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\Konstantin\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Python Scripts\Python 3.7 (64-bit)\python.exe','/Parcer_GUI_test.py'])
def window():

    eel.init('web')   
    eel.start('index.html', size=(700, 700))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window()
```

Вот моя попытка отследить нажатие с помощью js:

```
async function Parce(){
    let select = document.querySelector('select');
    let button = document.querySelector('input');
    select.addEventListener('change', click);
    function click(){
        let choice = select.value;
        if(button.onclick){
            if(choice === 'Rozetka'){
         eel.Parce;
    }
            }
                    }
                            }
```

Вот фрагмент HTML:

```
<h1>Parcer</h1>
   <div class = 'turple'>
    <form>
        <select id="shop" name="shop">
          <option value="Rozetka">Rozetka</option>
          <option value="Allo">Allo</option>
          <option value="Comfy">Comfy</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" onclick="click()" value="Parce this fucking shit">
      </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, вы не на тот элемент повесили EventListener
Ну в общем виде можно вот так:

1. вешаете ивент типа click на кнопку
2. Если в селекте значение Rozetka, то делаете что-то дальше.

```js
    let select = document.querySelector('select');
    let button = document.querySelector('input');
    button.addEventListener('click', click);
    function click(){
        if(select.value === 'Rozetka'){
            alert("Parsing time!")
         
    }
            }
```

```html
<h1>Parcer</h1>
   <div class = 'turple'>
    <form>
        <select id="shop" name="shop">
          <option value="Rozetka">Rozetka</option>
          <option value="Allo">Allo</option>
          <option value="Comfy">Comfy</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button"  value="Parce this fucking shit">
      </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Странно, но при нажатии на кнопку - ничего не происходит

Comment: Я все понял, просто функцию не вызвал, спасибо огромное за помощь!